# Get pixels from bitmap, display them results in wrong order

Tags: android, image, bitmap, pixel

I just wrote some code which grabs an image, stores it's pixels into an array and displays every pixel again, so that finally the grabbed image should be shown.

I took following image:
[image]

It's an 32x32 png image that I chose to use as an example.

That's my output:

[image]

As You might see, the result has far more pixels than 32x32.

Here's how my code looks:

First, an array was created that should get all the pixel informations of the image:

```
private Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
private int w = b.getWidth;
private int h = b.getHeight;
private int pixels = w*h;
```

Then I used a method to store the bitmap's pixels into the array:

```
b.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
```

I thought this should be it, now I can draw the pixels to my View:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  Paint p = new Paint();
  for(int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
      p.setColor(Color.parseColor(String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & pixelImage.pixels[i+i*j]))));
      canvas.drawRect(i, j, i+1, j+1, paint);
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea where my error is, maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: This is test/practice code, right? Even drawing a unicolored surface pixel by pixel in Java is expensive. And you're... formatting and parsing strings for... each pixel!?!

Comment: I kinda like the 2nd one better...

Comment: Yes it's just a test code

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is wrong, and frequently a bit wtf-y.  There's no reason for String.format to even come into it, I'm not even sure where you're going there.  And drawRect is not the way to do it.  Try:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
      p.setColor(pixels[i*bmp.getWidth()+j]);
      canvas.drawPoint(j, i, paint);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, I am sure that my coding is not the most efficient way to do it... 
First of all, thanks for Your idea, and second, how would You change the code to do it a little more efficient?
Best regards